# Laravel one to one relationship without foreign key

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, relational-database

I have two tables the **posts** table and the **categories** table.

Each post has one category only.

> What I am trying to do

Connect each post with one category ID without a foreign key.

> Why I am trying to do this

Because I don't want to duplicate in every post the category word I just want to duplicate the category ID.

> PostsController.php code

```
$posts = Post::orderBy('id', 'DESC') -> limit(16) -> get();

@foreach($posts as $post)

dd($post -> categories() -> cat);

@endforeach
```

> Posts.php model code

```
class Post extends Model
{
    public function category() {
        return $this->hasOne('App\Category');
    }
}
```

> Problem

I get an error to ask me for foreign key while I don't have foreign key in the categories table.

Comment: What is your question/problem ?

Comment: @El_Matella edited

Comment: I think this is impossible, you can't have a relationship without a foreign key...if there is no foreign key then there is no relationship...someone correct me if I'm wrong

Comment: @lewis4u You can have navigation property (not DB relationship but model relationship) without a foreign key. See my answer below....

Answer (score 13):

It's not necessary to have FK relationship. If you have a way to tell Laravel about how to find related record, it can do it for you. e.g.

```
class Post extends Model
{
    public function category() {
        return $this->hasOne('App\Category','id','category_id');
    }
}
```

Above will tell Laravel that when you ask for `category` property in `post`, it should take `category_id` from post table & look for `id` in category table. If both matches, it will give you matched category.

Comment: nice! It helped me a lot :D

Comment: "FK relationship" should say "Foreign Key Constraint" or better yet, "It's not necessary to have FK relationship." could be removed altogether. That statement is wrong as worded and doen't have anything to do with the problem or the correct answer that makes up the rest of your post

Answer (score 3):

Relation should be `belongsTo()`:

```
public function category() {
    return $this->belongsTo('App\Category');
}
```

And the `posts` table should have `category_id` anyway to make it work, however you can use it without [foreign key constraint](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/migrations#foreign-key-constraints).

Comment: Hi Alexey, I respect you the most of all other Laravel experts here on SO, So one simple question if you have 2 models I think it is not possible to have a relationship between them without a foreign key...I mean this is the basic principle of relationship databases. No foreign key == no relationship? Do you agree?

Comment: @lewis4u yes, I agree, as I said in my answer you need to use a key like `category_id` anyway. But you can use relationship without defining [foreign key constraints](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/migrations#foreign-key-constraints).

Answer (score 0):

```
class Post extends Model
{
    public function category() {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Category','id','category_id');
    }
}
```

It works for me perfectly.